# txt file is read correctly, forth line and beyond can't be recognized

Tags: java, string, file, path, contains

My program has to read a **txt file with for lines of strings**, and than search for a name contained in the txt file. If found it has to print "Found!" if not found "Not found.". It works fine, execpt that it doesn't recognize everything beyond the forth line in the txt file and prints "Not found.".

```java
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IsItInTheFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // initialize Scanner and ArrayList list
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // declare which file must be read
        System.out.println("Name of the file:");
        String fileName = scanner.nextLine();


        try (Scanner file = new Scanner(Paths.get(fileName))) {

            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Search for:");
                String searchedFor = scanner.nextLine();
                String writer = file.nextLine();
                if (writer.contains(searchedFor)) {
                    System.out.println("Found!");
                    break;
                } else if (!writer.contains(searchedFor)){
                    System.out.println("Not found.");
                    break;
                }
            }

        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Reading the file " + fileName + " failed.");
        }

    }
}
```

the names.txt file looks like this:

```
ada
arto
leena
testi
```

I can't understand why the forth line and beyond says "Not Found." even if it is correctly implemented and exactly written in the console.
Anyone know why and can explain it to me?
So why

Comment: What data are you searching for?

Comment: String. The forth line "testi".

Comment: So every time it asks you for input to search for you say `testi`? Or are you saying that when you do it for the fourth line it doesn't work?

Comment: For example it asks me what i am searching for, I input "testi" and cause is there it should say "Found!". But it prints "Not found." For the first three lines with ada, arto and leena it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the value of `writer` each time?

Comment: No, how would it help me? To be precise, how should I do that. The whole program just can print Found or Not found

Comment: For debugging purposes so you can see the values you are comparing in the code to investigate why it doesn't think they match. You can add `System.out.println(searchedFor + " != " + writer);` Just after the line printing 'Not found.'

Comment: It tells me:
testi != ada

So he compares it with ada? The first name? How can I solvethis, it makes no sense for me right now.

Comment: What you are doing is going through each one and comparing it against your input each time. If you move the line where you take the input to search for outside the while loop I think you will achieve what you are looking for if I understand your intention correctly.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this later.